# Why in. NETCORE 3.1, with Autofac, property registration is not allowed

Tags: asp.net

Property registration can't get data, but constructor registration is OK. This problem has been bothering me for a day. Help me

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDLsX.png)

Comment: services.AddControllers(options =>
            {
                options.Filters.Add(typeof(PowerFilter));
            }).AddControllersAsServices()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new DatetimeJsonConverter()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, in ASP.NET Core 3, the framework resolves dependent services of controller using container (in this case Autofac), but not resolves the controller itself using container.

To make framework resolve controller using container, you will need to call [`AddControllersAsServices`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvccoremvccorebuilderextensions.addcontrollersasservices?view=aspnetcore-3.1):

```
services.AddControllers().AddControllersAsServices();
```

After that, controllers should be resolved by Autofac container, and properties should be auto-wired.